# How to increase the width of sub fxml file when maximize the size of window in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am new in javafx and I used following code to display the sub fxml file in main design. But now I am facing problem with design part.When I maximize the size of the main design the sub design will not stretch. Which make lot of space at right side and bottom.
I have created sample code for make you easy to understand please download it from following link Please View this and let me know how can I solve it. Run it and do action you will know what i mean in above.

www.anamol.com.np/Example.rar

Comment: dont upload youre code anywhere, post your code simply in code tags.

Comment: I try to paste but i got problem with it so sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have not downloaded the source but i think an AnchorPane would make it.
And set following:

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(yourNode, 0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(yourNode, 0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(yourNode, 0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(yourNode, 0);
```

Comment: I used this code to implement my code so please tell me how to use your code on it
  try {
            Center.getChildren().clear();
            Center.getChildren().add((Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml")));//call the home display xml
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainDesignController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }